# error: git-credential-osxkeychain died of signal 11

Tags: ios, git, github, keychain

I have installed github version 0.8.4,
but when i try to fetch something from git, it is showing this message.

```
Fetching all tracking branches from Queue-iOS completed successfully.

command: git fetch Queue-iOS

error: git-credential-osxkeychain died of signal 11
error: git-credential-osxkeychain died of signal 11
error: git-credential-osxkeychain died of signal 11
error: git-credential-osxkeychain died of signal 11
From https://github.com/appstute/Queue-iOS
   59bb075..b2da838  master     -> Queue-iOS/master
```

It is a problem regarding keychain,
when i go for pull from git hub, the following message is displayed

```
Pulling all tracking branches from Queue-iOS encountered an error.

command: git pull Queue-iOS

error: git-credential-osxkeychain died of signal 11
error: git-credential-osxkeychain died of signal 11
error: git-credential-osxkeychain died of signal 11
error: git-credential-osxkeychain died of signal 11
You asked to pull from the remote 'Queue-iOS', but did not specify
a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote
for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line.

error = 1
```

Here Queue-iOS is the local folder I have configured on git. Please help.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git This article fixed it for me.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I am using Mac OS X 10.7.5.  I recently downloaded git 1.8.1.2 for Mac.  Having it installed, I bumped into the same signal 11 error message when running:

`$git credential-osxkeychain`

which in turn runs:

`/usr/local/git/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain`

Signal 11 is SEGFAULT which might indicate a bug (e.g. dereferencing a null pointer) with the `git-credential-osxkeychain` program.

I followed instructions on [caching your github password](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git) and grabbed a new copy of `git-credential-osxkeychain` from S3. That resolved the problem. The new copy is of different size which makes me guess the bug has been patched.

In the meantime, I believe using a URL like `git@github.com:yang3wei/octopress-3-in-one` in the config should also work around the problem as it bypasses HTTPS and uses SSH instead where the key chain helper is not invoked any more.

Comment: Worked for me - I also suspect a bug in whatever version of git-credential-osxkeychain I had.

Answer (score 8):

The **error message** is being thrown by a git [credential helper](https://github.com/pah/git-credential-helper). It is supposed to be a way for git to avoid  asking for your username and password on every push (see [here](https://github.com/blog/1104-credential-caching-for-wrist-friendly-git-usage)).

I don't know why it is dying but, if you want to stop using it (and avoid seeing the error message), delete your system gitconfig file.

On my system (OSX 10.6.8) I did it with: `sudo rm /usr/local/git/etc/gitconfig` because the only setting in the file was for the credential helper. Check yours first!

Since you are getting **two** death messages, you may also have the setting in your own `~/.gitconfig` file or even your project's. Edit those and remove the credential helper block.

As you noted, the problem with the credential helper doesn't stop git from working. The next step is to find out why the helper fails!

Comment: Removing via `sudo rm /usr/local/git/etc/gitconfig` fixed this issue for me. As OP stated, ensure your config only contains the credential helper.

Comment: i installed git svn and this started happening, deleting that filed resolved it.

Answer (score 6):

I got it!
Try to modify the contents of .git/config file in your project's root directory.

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/yang3wei/octopress-3-in-one.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

To:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:yang3wei/octopress-3-in-one
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: For anyone reading, this answer is the 100% correct one, particularly for older installations like OS X 10.6.8. The credentials are being fed wrongly to github by the git engine as they were set up wrong by the git tool, and the correction above resolves that. You need to do this separately for each project because the config file is specific to the project. Thanks, yang3wei!

Comment: Confirmed, also under OS X 10.6.8. (Thanks.)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error every time I did a git pull. I realized that I did not have the git-credential binary which I got from(under Where's the Mac version?):
https://github.com/blog/1104-credential-caching-for-wrist-friendly-git-usage and followed the steps mentioned there. It started working the way I expected to.
Hope this helps!

Comment: somehow i solved this problem,now keychain error message is not appearing if i pull or push something from github.                      what i did is i used the following link and downloaded the git file,in which the above problem was not happening. i also removed my existing git file from applications  and did  everything fro first.I don't know the keychain issue is solved internally or not but my problem is solved for the time being .thank u guys for your advices.           http://mac.github.com

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the following errors when I tried to use the git version 1.8.1.3 after upgrading:

`git-credential-osxkeychain died of signal 11`

When I was doing git pull, I would get

`fatal: https://github.com/.../../info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?`

I am guessing it had to do with my previous invalid github credentials in the keychain.

- Opened keychain access tool using Command space
- searched for github in the keychain access tool
- removed all the entries related to github (since I no longer needed it)
- followed the setup git password caching section again [setup git](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git)
- it worked

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with git in the error: git-credential-osxkeychain died of signal 11

Not cloning repo since http, because you need verification everytime that your need do a push or pull

Answer (score 1):

I'm using SourceTree (on a Mac) and I had the same issue.

First I entered the following commands in the Terminal:

```
curl -s -O \
https://github-media-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/osx/git-credential-osxkeychain
chmod u+x git-credential-osxkeychain
sudo mv git-credential-osxkeychain \
"$(dirname $(which git))/git-credential-osxkeychain"
git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
```

Then I had to switch to system git in SourceTree:

SourceTree > Preferences > Git > Use System Git