# Getting git-credential-osxkeychain error while using 'git push' command

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have git version 1.8.4.2 installed. Upon executing `git push` I got following error:

```
**error: git-credential-osxkeychain died of signal 11**
Password for 'https://example@bitbucket.org': 
error: git-credential-osxkeychain died of signal 11
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 262 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://example@bitbucket.org/example/repoX.git
   14d71eb..dabf093  master -> master
```

I also executed `git credential-osxkeychain` but still same error.

the file `gitconfig` only contains:

```
[credential]
        helper = osxkeychain
```

Let me tell you file did commit and push successfully.

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: git-credential-osxkeychain died of signal 11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272634/error-git-credential-osxkeychain-died-of-signal-11)

Comment: I guess not because I am not getting: `git: 'credential-osxkeychain' is not a git command. See 'git --help' `

Comment: I guess you didnt really read the answer. have you tried re-downloading the credential-helper?

Comment: @NevikRehnel Yes I did read but I did not install newer as the the link(https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git) said it needs to be installed when it was not installed.

If you suggest to download anyway, can you please tell where to put the file so that git could recognize it?

Comment: Thanks @NevikRehnel it worked.. I checked my paths again and found it was not pointing to write file...