# Can't push to GitLab, remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, phpstorm, gitlab

**Problem**
While trying to push to my project on gitlab.com in PhpStorm, I get the following error:

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.com/me/myrepo.git'
```

I don't see any other error messages like on other peoples similar questions.

**What I've tried**
I tried pushing via the terminal as well with `git push origin master` but to no avail. I also tried some of the things I saw on similar questions like changing the http buffer: `git config http.postBuffer 524288000`. That, unfortunately, didn't change the result either.

What I also tried is creating a new project and pushing to that new origin, which yielded other error messages. I also tried changing to `ssh`, but when pushing the push button it wants to push all commits that were ever made. I wasn't sure if that was a good idea, so I didn't try it.
This is what comes when trying to `git pull --rebase`:

```
git pull --rebase 
error: merge-base died of signal 11
error: fetch died of signal 11
```

also happens with full syntax `git pull --rebase origin master`.

**Setup**
I am using PhpStorm and have 17 commits that need to be pushed, since I've been having this problem for a while. My repo is a project on gitlab.com.

```
git --version
git version 2.17.0
```

Comment: Have you tried the syntax proposed in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to?answertab=active#tab-top ? Are you sure you have the rights to push on this project ? Maybe branch is protected ?

Comment: Yes, it is my project and as stated in the question, I have pushed before this problem. I haven't changed any settings on the repo either. I did try the syntax in that answer, but also fail. I will add that to the question

Comment: Is this the complete error you give? Or does git tell you something else after ?

Comment: that's the full error message in the phpstorm terminal : /

Comment: possible duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272634/error-git-credential-osxkeychain-died-of-signal-11 ?

Comment: I'm not using `credential-osxkeychain` and I'm not on MacOS

Comment: Fixed with `IPQoS throughput`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54102804/how-to-fix-packet-write-wait-connection-to-broken-pipe-error-in-git/74563678#74563678

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug in my git installation, at least that's what I believe. After I got an update, the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Was there hint message along with the error?
Sometimes the local repo isn't in sync.
I did this:

`git pull --rebase`

`git push`

Comment: no, unfortunately no other message than the 2 I posted in the question. I will try that though

Comment: didn't work, I get `error: merge-base died of signal 11
error: fetch died of signal 11`

Comment: Perhaps you can try to force your push with `git push -f`