# How to fix 'packet_write_wait: Connection to ... Broken pipe' error in Git

Tags: git, github, ssh

How can I fix the problem when I `git push` files to my remote repositories and it throw the error 'packet_write_wait: Connection to 13.250.177.223 port 22: Broken pipe'?Before `git push`, I had clone the project from the remote and `git add`, `git commit` successfully.

I haved tried `git pull`, `git config http.postBuffer 52428800`, but it doesn't work.

```
HP@EverChan MINGW32 /d/ChromeDownload/jiaoben5049/meetingDemo (master)
$ git pull
packet_write_wait: Connection to 52.74.223.119 port 22: Broken pipe
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
HP@EverChan MINGW32 /d/ChromeDownload/jiaoben5049/meetingDemo (master)
$ git config http.postBuffer 52428800
HP@EverChan MINGW32 /d/ChromeDownload/jiaoben5049/meetingDemo (master)
$ git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 46, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (46/46), done.
packet_write_wait: Connection to 13.250.177.223 port 22: Broken pipe
Writing foabjecttals:   8:% The  (4/4remote end hung up u6nex)pectedly
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipe
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
HP@EverChan MINGW32 /d/ChromeDownload/jiaoben5049/meetingDemo (master)
$ git push -u origin master
packet_write_wait: Connection to 13.250.177.223 port 22: Broken pipe
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 11):

What worked for me in the context of pushing my repo to github was adding *IPQoS=throughput* to my config file in ~/.ssh/config. The other steps for making sure SSH is are set up correctly, added to your Github account etc. are detailed [here](https://github.com/tanyagupta/codeblogs/blob/development/githubHowTos/howto.md)

Comment: Same problem with [ssh keys for BitBucket on macOS](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html#SetupanSSHkey-ssh2), and `IPQoS=throughput` was the only thing that helped!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your SSH URL for your remote origin does work:

```
ssh -T yourServer
```

Its IP address should not change.

See if the issue persists with the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) ([`PortableGit-2.20.1-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.20.1.windows.1/PortableGit-2.20.1-64-bit.7z.exe)), uncompress in C:\Git, and set a [simplified PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53606336/6309) in a CMD session.

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

---

Note: you can see arror messages with `packet_write()` failing.
Before, we gave an extra error message unnecessarily, which has been corrected with Git 2.32 (Q2 2021).

See [commit 332ec96](https://github.com/git/git/commit/332ec963bc6fedc0ca9c0b5a66ea842d7fbd6baa) (15 Apr 2021) by [Matheus Tavares (`matheustavares`)](https://github.com/matheustavares).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 279a2e6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/279a2e637a69afd6157e8287c2599e8ae5e6cb8c), 30 Apr 2021)</sup>

> ### [`pkt-line`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/332ec963bc6fedc0ca9c0b5a66ea842d7fbd6baa): do not report packet write errors twice
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Matheus Tavares</sup>

> On `write()` errors, `packet_write()` dies with the same error message that is already printed by its callee, `packet_write_gently()`.
> This produces an unnecessarily verbose and repetitive output:
>
> ```
> error: packet write failed 
> fatal: packet write failed: <strerror() message>
> ```
>
> In addition to that, `packet_write_gently()` does not always fulfill its caller expectation that errno will be properly set before a non-zero return.
> In particular, that is not the case for a "data exceeds max packet size" error.
> So, in this case, `packet_write()` will call `die_errno()` and print an `strerror(errno)` message that might be totally unrelated to the actual error.
>
> Fix both those issues by turning `packet_write()` and `packet_write_gently()` into wrappers to a common lower level function that doesn't print the error message, but instead returns it on a buffer for the caller to `die()` or `error()` as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me alot, try out this:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory /var/www/html/Your_Project_Folder
```

Answer (score 0):

For gitlab/github, add to client ssh_config:

```
Host *
IPQoS throughput                                                                                                                            
TCPKeepAlive yes
```

See here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/gl-infra/reliability/-/issues/4849

Comment: Also you may try: `git config http.postBuffer 524288000; git config ssh.postBuffer 524288000`