# Git, fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly, while pushing to git

Tags: git, gitlab

When I run following command

```
git push origin master
```

After compression (100%) it shows

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to 169.47.136.242 port 22: Broken pipe
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I am adding snapshot of my work

[image]

Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix 'packet\_write\_wait: Connection to ... Broken pipe' error in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54102804/how-to-fix-packet-write-wait-connection-to-broken-pipe-error-in-git)

Comment: I have tried this but found no luck

Comment: Ow, sorry, I hoped it would be a good starting point in case you didn't already read it. Also, it might be useful to describe in the question the steps you took to solve the problem, even if unsuccessful.